# Visual Studio error with strange characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, compiler-errors

I have a really unusual error when I try to build/clean a Visual Studio project. When I try, I get the below error

[image: Error1]

I've never seen this before. I've narrowed it down to WebGrease. I deleted the package and restored it, but it just happened again. I don't know what's wrong with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened due to the project's DLL's being NTFS compressed. Because of this, Visual Studio couldn't read it. I recloned it and everything is fine now.